# AEM Xpath query search inside specific page URL for specific property

Tags: xpath, aem

I have the following structure:

> content/site/**level0**/services/mypage
>
> content/site/**level1**/services/mypage
>
> content/site/**level2**/services/mypage
>
> content/site/**level3**/services/mypage

Level0 - is a folder holding blueprints for all pages.
Level1,2,3 - are different folders that contain LIVE COPIES for all blueprints.

I am trying to search for properties inside a specific page (unique page URL) for any node that contains a specific property value. The results need to show the full path of the node containing `myvalue`.

So far I have 3 queries:

```
/jcr:root/content/site//element(**mypage**, cq:Page)[jcr:contains(., 'myvalue')]
```

This works but I don't have the full node path as a results.

It will return just `cq:Pages` that are holding somewhere `myvalue`.

```
/jcr:root/content/site//*[jcr:contains(@*, 'myvalue')]
```

I can now see the full path of the nodes as results but I just want to search inside "mypage" not the full site.

```
/jcr:root/content/site//mypage//*[jcr:contains(@*, 'myvalue')]
```

Because the environment is huge I see this message:

> The query read or traversed more than 100000 nodes.

How can I get a mix of query 1 (I say the name of the page URL I need to search inside for) and query 2 (show me all nodes that are holding my specific property value)?

Comment: Do you have to use xpath? Could you use SQL2? And how exactly are you executing the query? Java? crx/de ?

Comment: Hi Ahmed Musallam - Yes I really need to use xpath. And yes, using CRX/DE. If there is no way to do this, I'm open to other suggestions. Thank you!